# Shell script will not be executed

Tags: android, shell

I've CM12.1 on my Galaxy S3. I'm trying to set up SSHD. At the moment everything is working fine, except the last step: start the sshd demon at start-up.

The problem is that the script

> /data/local/userinit.sh

will be executed, but
the call in it not anymore.

Here is the script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

if [ -e /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd ]
then
   log -p i -t userinit "Launching /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd--before"
   /system/bin/sh /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd
   log -p i -t userinit "Launching /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd--after"
fi
```

The script 99sshd is very simple, just for debugging:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

log -p i -t userinit "Executing /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd"
```

And here is the result from logcat:

> userinit - Launching /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd--before
>
> userinit - Launching /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd--after

Missing is the message:

> userinit - Executing /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd

How could it happen?!

Comment: Can you run it manually as a test?

Comment: Yes, from the terminal no problem.

Comment: ok folks, I found, that the file system isn't ready somehow: the scipt isn't there at the moment of execution.
Any help from sy who knows very well the android boot process is very appreciated.

Comment: [this](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_sshd#Problem_with_SELinux_.2F_SEAndroid_on_CM_12.1) may be related.

Comment: Just a guess here, as I've no G3 to test with.  This line: "/system/bin/sh /data/local/userinit.d/99sshd", wouldn't that execute *99sshd* in a subshell?  Perhaps that accounts for what's missing., i.e. the same way the '$x' is lost here: **echo -e "x=yes\necho \$x\n" > foo ; bash foo ; echo :$x:**.

Comment: Hey sudoman, you are the king! :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

init.d and userinit.d support [removed](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/41nlbi/how_do_we_get_initd_working_in_cm/) from CM12 and CM13